# Magento 1.8.0.0 Failed install PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-48-23

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, security, patches, supee-7405

I can't install patch **PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-48-23** into project. Error with this file :

```
checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 309.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 379.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
```

My applied patches:  SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-1533, SUPEE-5998,  SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, 
Any ideas or suggestions how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The patch failed because `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml` did not have the expected content.

### Solution:

1. back up this file
2. replace it with  the original file from Magento 1.8.0.0
3. compare with your backup to see what you changed
4. apply the patch
5. either make your changes again (Manually, do not use the backed up file because it is unpatched!), or (recommended) find a way to implement your changes without changing core files, for example with a custom admin theme or an observer in a custom module

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason could be that you have modified the two following files:

- `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml`
- `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml`

I suggest you backup those two files (rename theme with .backup) and download the original file here:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.8.0.0/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.8.0.0/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml

Then try to apply the patch again. Once it's done compare the files with your backup file and reapply your custom changes